# Why I am receiving java.lang.Boolean cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. when I actually Provided it?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Here is the module which includes another module FeatureXModule

```
interface FragmentModule {
@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(
    modules = {
             FeatureXModule.class
    })

  @Binds
  @Group
  @IntoSet
  IntentGroup bindDefaultGroup(DefaulGroup group);

 @Binds
 @Group
 @IntoSet
 IntentGroup bindGroup(Group group);

}
```

where Group class is look like this

```
class Group{

@Inject
public Group(@IsEnabled boolean isEnabled) {}
 }
```

and here is the next module which first module is depend on

```
interface FeatureXModule {
@Provides
@IsEnabled
static boolean provideXEanbled() {
    return true;// TODO: change it
}
}
```

When I build this I receive .IsEnabled java.lang.Boolean cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

and the interesting is when I move the `bind` methods to the second module the app builds 
What is the wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are the modules composed? In other words, does one module know about the bindings of the other?

The way to do this is to use `@Includes`:

```
@Module(includes = {FeatureModule.class})
interface FeatureXModule {
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769365/dagger-2-what-does-moduleincludes-do) for more detail.

Alternatively, a Component can have the bindings from multiple modules:

```
@Component(modules={Module1.class, Module2.class})
```

Comment: What is the difference ContributesAndroidInjector vs include, because I have ContributesAndroidInjector .

Comment: That sound right. Can you include that code as well?

Comment: I meant this @ContributesAndroidInjector(
    modules = {
             FeatureXModule.class
    })